# Elements not displayed properly with height: 100vh

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want the page to be 100vh in height, so that there are no scrollbars on the whole page. For some reason the main grid is bigger than the screen size and some of the elements are getting clipped.

```
<html>
    <body>

        <div id="root">
            <div class="app_container">
                <div class="navigation">
                    <div class="navigation_logo_container"><img src="/icon.9c86b69e.png"
                            class="navigation_logo"><span>Sample</span></div>
                    <div class="navigation_buttons_container">
                        <div><span>Sample</span></div>
                        <div><span>Sample</span></div>
                        <div><span>Sample</span></div>
                        <div><span>Sample</span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="game">
                    <div class="quiz"><span class="question_text">Sample</span>
                        <div class="answer_choices">
                            <div class="answer_choice"><span>Sample</span></div>
                            <div class="answer_choice"><span>Sample</span></div>
                            <div class="answer_choice"><span>Sample</span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/GuacomoleCyclone/pen/RwKjmzO

Comment: Use `min-height:100vh` of `height:100vh`

Comment: Have you removed the default margin from the `body`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on your setup the 100vh is working but your children are adding to the cause...

Meaning you have nav with height on fit-content...so lets just say ***65px***;

but then you have game div at `height: 100%`

If you remove that nav it works as you want, ..so for easily to solve this, you would have to also equate that extra height besides 100% game(nav height).

So meaning you would have to give:

```
.game {
  height: calc(100% - 65px); 
}
```

There are other ways to solve your setup without doing this but this is one of them.

Comment: Thanks! I used another solution, but you have helped me understand the root of the problem! I did:
`app.container{
 display:flex;
 flex-direction: column
}`